# R: Passing named function arguments from vector

Tags: r, vector

How can I achieve that I can pass named function arguments from a named vector?

```
vec <- c(b=5, a=3)
fun <- function(a, b) {
  browser()
  message(sprintf("a=%s", a))
  message(sprintf("b=%s", b))
}
fun(vec) # should return a=3, b=5
```

I mean in this example, I want to dynmically pass the values from `vec` into `fun` without doing `a=vec$a`, `b=vec$b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R we can use `eval(bquote())`  with `..()` and `splice = TRUE`.

In  {rlang} we can use `inject` with `!!!` instead.

Alternatively to the existing `do.call()` answer (see above) {rlang} has `exec()` which takes also an atomic vector instead of a list.

```r
vec <- c(b = 5,  a = 3)

fun <- function(a, b) {
  message(sprintf("a=%s", a))
  message(sprintf("b=%s", b))
}

# base R
eval(bquote(fun(..(vec)), splice = TRUE)) 
#> a=3
#> b=5

# rlang
rlang::inject(fun(!!! vec))
#> a=3
#> b=5

# rlang
rlang::exec(fun, !!! vec)
#> a=3
#> b=5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this in R, but typically you will need to convert your named *vector* to a named *list* using `as.list` at some point.

For example using `with` :

```r
with(as.list(vec), {
  fun(a, b)
})
#> a=3
#> b=5
```

Or `do.call`

```r
do.call(fun, as.list(vec))
#> a=3
#> b=5
```

If you are using the function frequently and want to avoid the boilerplate, another option is to use a wrapper function to make it easy to call by just passing `vec`

```r
f <- function(v) eval(as.call(c(quote(fun), as.list(v))))

f(vec)
#> a=3
#> b=5
```

Note that `$` can't be used to subset named vectors, so your can't *even* do `fun(a = vec$a, b = vec$b)` ; you would need to do `fun(a = vec['a'], b = vec['b'])`. Using `$` requires a `list`, a `data.frame` or an `environment`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
vec <- c(b=5, a=3)
fun <- function(v) {
  browser()
  message(sprintf("a=%s", v['a']))
  message(sprintf("b=%s", v['b']))
}
fun(vec) # should return a=3, b=5
```

**Output:**

```
> fun(vec) # should return a=3, b=5
Called from: fun(vec)
Browse[1]> 
debug at #3: message(sprintf("a=%s", v["a"]))
Browse[2]> 
a=3
debug at #4: message(sprintf("b=%s", v["b"]))
Browse[2]> 
b=5
>
```