# Returning actual function argument from vector in function call with lapply in R

Tags: r, function, lapply

Please consider the following.

I want to use `lapply()` to subsequently apply several function arguments stored in a character vector to some other function. A minimal reproducible example could be to apply two or more "families" to the `glm()` function. Please note that the example might be nonsensical for applying such families and is used for illustration purposes only.

The following is taken from the example in `?glm()`

```r
counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
treatment <- gl(3,3)
data.frame(treatment, outcome, counts) # showing data
```

We can now run a GLM with family "gaussian" or "poisson"

```r
glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = "gaussian")
glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = "poisson")
```

This could also be "automated" by creating a character vector with these family names:

```r
families <- c("poisson", "gaussian")
```

And using this in an `lapply()` function.

But once this runs, the returned function call does not return the family names anymore but the anonymous function argument `x`.

```r
lapply(families, function(x) glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = x))
#> [[1]]
#> 
#> Call:  glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = x)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)     outcome2     outcome3   treatment2   treatment3  
#>   3.045e+00   -4.543e-01   -2.930e-01   -3.242e-16   -2.148e-16  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 8 Total (i.e. Null);  4 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       10.58 
#> Residual Deviance: 5.129     AIC: 56.76
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> 
#> Call:  glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = x)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)     outcome2     outcome3   treatment2   treatment3  
#>   2.100e+01   -7.667e+00   -5.333e+00    2.221e-15    2.971e-15  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 8 Total (i.e. Null);  4 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       176 
#> Residual Deviance: 83.33     AIC: 57.57
```

---

**Question:**
How can the family names from the vector `families` be preserved/shown in the function call after `lapply()`?

---

**Desired outcome:**
The outcome should look like this:

```r
#> [[1]]
#> 
#> Call:  glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = "gaussian")
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)     outcome2     outcome3   treatment2   treatment3  
#>   3.045e+00   -4.543e-01   -2.930e-01   -3.242e-16   -2.148e-16  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 8 Total (i.e. Null);  4 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       10.58 
#> Residual Deviance: 5.129     AIC: 56.76
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> 
#> Call:  glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = "poisson")
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)     outcome2     outcome3   treatment2   treatment3  
#>   2.100e+01   -7.667e+00   -5.333e+00    2.221e-15    2.971e-15  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 8 Total (i.e. Null);  4 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       176 
#> Residual Deviance: 83.33     AIC: 57.57
```

I tried `eval(bquote(x))` as suggested here: [R: Passing named function arguments from vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72039909/r-passing-named-function-arguments-from-vector), but this did not work. See:

```r
lapply(families, function(x) glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = eval(bquote(x))))
#> [[1]]
#> 
#> Call:  glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = eval(bquote(x)))
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)     outcome2     outcome3   treatment2   treatment3  
#>   3.045e+00   -4.543e-01   -2.930e-01   -3.242e-16   -2.148e-16  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 8 Total (i.e. Null);  4 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       10.58 
#> Residual Deviance: 5.129     AIC: 56.76
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> 
#> Call:  glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = eval(bquote(x)))
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)     outcome2     outcome3   treatment2   treatment3  
#>   2.100e+01   -7.667e+00   -5.333e+00    2.221e-15    2.971e-15  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 8 Total (i.e. Null);  4 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       176 
#> Residual Deviance: 83.33     AIC: 57.57
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more direct way to do this would be to build and evaluate the call directly inside `lapply`

```r
lapply(families, function(x) {
  eval(as.call(list(quote(glm), 
               formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment, 
               data = quote(df), 
               family = x)))
  })
#> [[1]]
#> 
#> Call:  glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = "poisson", 
#>     data = df)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)     outcome2     outcome3   treatment2   treatment3  
#>   3.045e+00   -4.543e-01   -2.930e-01    1.338e-15    1.421e-15  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 8 Total (i.e. Null);  4 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       10.58 
#> Residual Deviance: 5.129     AIC: 56.76
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> 
#> Call:  glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = "gaussian", 
#>     data = df)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)     outcome2     outcome3   treatment2   treatment3  
#>   2.100e+01   -7.667e+00   -5.333e+00    2.056e-16    7.252e-16  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 8 Total (i.e. Null);  4 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       176 
#> Residual Deviance: 83.33     AIC: 57.57
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

An approach could be to extract the family name and add it to the formula within each model object. For instance like this:

```r
lapply(families, \(fam) { model <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = fam); model$call[3] <- model$family$family; return(model)})
```

Output:

```r
[[1]]

Call:  glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = "poisson")

Coefficients:
(Intercept)     outcome2     outcome3   treatment2   treatment3  
  3.045e+00   -4.543e-01   -2.930e-01   -3.242e-16   -2.148e-16  

Degrees of Freedom: 8 Total (i.e. Null);  4 Residual
Null Deviance:      10.58 
Residual Deviance: 5.129    AIC: 56.76

[[2]]

Call:  glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = "gaussian")

Coefficients:
(Intercept)     outcome2     outcome3   treatment2   treatment3  
  2.100e+01   -7.667e+00   -5.333e+00    2.221e-15    2.971e-15  

Degrees of Freedom: 8 Total (i.e. Null);  4 Residual
Null Deviance:      176 
Residual Deviance: 83.33    AIC: 57.57
```

Depending on the purpose, you could also (just) name your elements in your vector and each list element would have its name.

```r
families <- c(poisson = "poisson", gaussian = "gaussian")
lapply(families, function(x) glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = x))
```

Output:

```r
$poisson

Call:  glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)     outcome2     outcome3   treatment2   treatment3  
  3.045e+00   -4.543e-01   -2.930e-01   -3.242e-16   -2.148e-16  

Degrees of Freedom: 8 Total (i.e. Null);  4 Residual
Null Deviance:      10.58 
Residual Deviance: 5.129    AIC: 56.76

$gaussian

Call:  glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)     outcome2     outcome3   treatment2   treatment3  
  2.100e+01   -7.667e+00   -5.333e+00    2.221e-15    2.971e-15  

Degrees of Freedom: 8 Total (i.e. Null);  4 Residual
Null Deviance:      176 
Residual Deviance: 83.33    AIC: 57.57
```

*Update with approach 1.*

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I accepted another answer because it was more concise. In the end I went with a mix of the shorter approach and your list naming solution.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another possible solution:

```r
families <- c("gaussian", "poisson") 
lapply(families, \(x) eval(parse(text=paste0("glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, 
  df, family = ", x, ")"))))

#> [[1]]
#> 
#> Call:  glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = gaussian, 
#>     data = df)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)     outcome2     outcome3   treatment2   treatment3  
#>   2.100e+01   -7.667e+00   -5.333e+00    8.729e-16    7.252e-16  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 8 Total (i.e. Null);  4 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       176 
#> Residual Deviance: 83.33     AIC: 57.57
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> 
#> Call:  glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = poisson, 
#>     data = df)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)     outcome2     outcome3   treatment2   treatment3  
#>   3.045e+00   -4.543e-01   -2.930e-01    1.011e-15    7.105e-16  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 8 Total (i.e. Null);  4 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       10.58 
#> Residual Deviance: 5.129     AIC: 56.76
```